# File copied by Docker seen as a directory

Tags: docker, boot2docker, stardog

I'm trying to dockerize a Stardog 3.1.3 community edition server. The container fails to start because it sees a directory instead of a license file. For the record, I'm on Windows. These are the steps I'm following:

Create a data container

```
docker create -v /data/stardog:/data/stardog --name stardog_data busybox /bin/true
```

Copy the local license key to the data container (not done in the Dockerfile that is mentioned below as the license is environment specific)

```
docker cp .\stardog\stardog-license-key.bin stardog_data:/stardog-license-key.bin
```

Create an image based on the following Dockerfile

```
docker build -t me/stardog .


FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk

ENV STARDOG_VER stardog-3.1.3
ENV STARDOG_HOME /data/stardog

COPY ${LOCAL_PATH}/${STARDOG_VER}.zip /
RUN unzip ${STARDOG_VER}.zip

WORKDIR /${STARDOG_VER}

CMD rm $STARDOG_HOME/system.lock || true && bin/stardog-admin server start && (tail -f $STARDOG_HOME/stardog.log &) && while (pidof java > /dev/null); do sleep 1; done
```

Run a Stardog container

```
docker run -d -p 5820:5820 --volumes-from stardog_data --name stardog me/stardog
```

When I execute `docker ps -a`, I see that the container is stopped after a couple of seconds:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
9559b22473e1        me/stardog               "/bin/sh -c 'rm $STAR"   26 minutes ago      Exited (1) 26 minutes ago                            stardog
2b929329e35e        busybox                  "/bin/true"              32 minutes ago      Created                                              stardog_data
```

When I check the logs with `docker logs stardog`, I'm getting this:

```
com.clarkparsia.license.InvalidLicenseException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin (Is a directory)
        at com.clarkparsia.license.LicenseValidator.validate(LicenseValidator.java:157)
        at com.complexible.stardog.StardogLicense.findLicense(StardogLicense.java:127)
        at com.complexible.stardog.StardogLicense.<init>(StardogLicense.java:70)
        at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.<init>(Stardog.java:158)
        at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.initialize(Stardog.java:263)
        at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.initialize(Stardog.java:254)
        at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.buildServer(Stardog.java:247)
        at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:144)
        at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:47)
        at com.complexible.stardog.cli.CLIBase.execute(CLIBase.java:54)
        at com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI.main(CLI.java:194)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at com.clarkparsia.license.LicenseValidator.validate(LicenseValidator.java:113)
        ... 10 more
Your Stardog license is invalid.  Please contact support@clarkparsia.com for information on obtaining a new license.
```

It seems that the license file is considered to be a directory. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: the doc at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ shows several cases where the destination becomes a directory, for example `SRC_PATH specifies a directory

    DEST_PATH does not exist
        DEST_PATH is created as a directory and the contents of the source directory are copied into this directory
` you should put the full path on source and dest

Comment: I don't see any recommendation regarding full paths, yet I've tried the following without success (same error): `C:\Users\xxx\stardog\stardog-license-key.bin stardog_data:/data/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin`. Also, AFAIK I'm in the following scenario: `SRC_PATH specifies a file,
DEST_PATH does not exist, the file is saved to a file created at DEST_PATH`. Any ideas?

Comment: the docker cp doc says `The cp command behaves like the Unix cp -a command in that directories are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible`

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant to the problem. Might just be my limited knowledge of linux. In my first comment, I did try `stardog_data:/data/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin`as CONTAINER:DEST_PATH, but to no avail. Can you pinpoint the problem? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your first example correct? Looks like you're copying outside of the "volume" path; `stardog_data:/stardog-license-key.bin`. What happens if you `docker cp stardog-license-key.bin stardom_data:/data/stardog/` (i.e. specify the directory that it should be copied into)

Comment: Hi @thaJeztah, that was wrong indeed, but if you check a couple of comments above, I did this it with the right path.

Comment: After further investigation, I seems to be a Windows related bug, see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21743. It works like a charm on a native Linux machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows related problem. I've tried these exact same steps on a native Ubuntu (14.04) machine and it works as expected. I've filed this as a [bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21743) and hopefully this gets fixed soon.